# IndexOutOfRangeException on Webservice

Tags: c#, sql, web-services, asmx, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm getting an IndexOutOfRangeException on a webservice I've

```
[WebMethod]
public Svar FindAgent(int agentCode)
{
    SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(@"data source = BABU110-PC; integrated security = true; database = SecretAgentDB"); //forbindelse
    // Vi burde lave noget try catch

    conn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = conn.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = @"select * from Agents where Code = " + agentCode;
    SqlDataReader rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    rdr.Read();

    Agent a = new Agent();
    a.Code = (int)rdr["Code"];
    a.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();
    rdr.Close();

    cmd.CommandText = @"select * from AgentLicense where AgentCode = " + a.Code;
    rdr = cmd.ExecuteReader(); // execute vores sql
    // Hvis der er flere skal der laves en løkke her
    // Read() giver true tilbage, hvis der var flere data.
    // Kan fx bruges i en while 
    rdr.Read();
    License l = new License();
    l.Id = (int)rdr["Id"];
    l.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString(); ------ GIVES ME THE IndexOutOfRangeException HERE
    //
    rdr.Close();

    Svar s = new Svar();
    s.A = a;
    s.L = l;

    return s;
}
```

I'm getting this error at `l.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();`

> System.IndexOutOfRangeException: Name
>   SecretAgentServiceCS4.asmx.cs:line 46,

which is at where `l.Name = rdr["Name"].ToString();` is at

Comment: Are you sure "Name" is a column in the reader's results?

Comment: I suspect `AgentLicence` table doesn't have the `Name` column.

Comment: AgentLicense has:
Id
AgentCode
LicenseId

Comment: it looks like you're looking for a.Name here instead of rdr["Name"].ToString(). However, this could probably be written much better. Use joins for your sql tables and retrieve the values from there. You're assigning your rdr object to one set of values, then reassigning your rdr object again to another set of values.